# Checking Role-based permissions on all actions in centralized or clean way in .Net applications

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I am trying to avoid the conventional:

```
if(!user.HasPermission(Actions.UpdateRecord))
{
 // code to update record
}
```

on a large number of permissions all over my application.

I am looking for a means of checking for permissions in an effective and  (if possible) elegant manner. 
In this case there are multiple actions within each permission.

Comment: How about the declarative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting a decorator on your dataaccess objects.  The decorator pattern is very useful for doing things like handling permissions.  Your dataAccess layer can do just data access and then your decorate those classes with something that handles permissions and permissions only.

It is very elegant...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: I'm sure by now your have figured it out... but the gist of it is that you create an interface.  Every place you use the object to be decorated you refer to it via the interface.  You inject the decorated object or get it via a factory which would return or inject a "decorated" object of the interface type.  The decorator is simply an object wrapper that wraps an object and adds functionality before passing control to the class it decorates.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  The important thing is that you want to encapsulate the concern of checking permissions.  One way to do this is with a strategy pattern.  Encapsulate the action in a class, and get the class via a factory method.  The factory can do the security check, and return a different strategy for disallowed actions.

For example:

```
public abstract class SecureAction
{
    public void PerformAction();
}

public class UpdateRecords : SecureAction
{
    public void PerformAction()
    {
        //code to do the update
    }
}

public class DoesNotHavePermissionAction : SecureAction
{
    public void PerformAction()
    {
        //code to handle missing permissions
    }
}

public class SecureActionFactory
{
    public void GetUpdateRecordsAction(User user)
    {
        if(user.HasPermissions(Actions.UpdateRecord)) {return new UpdateRecordsAction();}

        return new DoesNotHavePermissionAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem with this as well as strategy (which was the first idea) is that the signatures of the methods change for each class and method.

Comment: That can be handled in the creation of the action objects in the factory.

Comment: The client code would need to be able to call the methods on the action class with their different signatures. So, in a factory the class that is constructed implements an interface. I will have multiple action classes that will all have totally different methods with different signatures so factory does not seem that it will work here.